# polylang translation of a custom post created by wp_insert_post()

Tags: plugin-polylang

I am in trouble. I have a travel site...I have created a page where users can write a form to insert their houses.

The houses are of course a custom post type.

This is a piece of my code:

```
...
some validation here

if ($idarticolo = wp_insert_post($post)) {

    //lingua
    global $polylang;
    $lang = pll_current_language();
    $polylang->set_post_language($idarticolo, $lang);

    ...
```

everything works fine, the house is inserted in my current language; but when I try to translate this post from admin panel, I get an error.

The post is not translated, and no language is detected.

Please help!!!...many thanks in advance!

M.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Polylang has an undocumented pll_save_post API method. See here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/programmatically-set-post-language-and-translations

Answer (score 4):

Ok Riaan,

thank you for your reply.

I solved in this way (maybe can be helpful):

```
if ($idarticolo = wp_insert_post($post, true)) {

    // inserisco l'articolo nelle altre lingue: En Es Fr
    $idarticoloEn = wp_insert_post($post, true);
    $idarticoloEs = wp_insert_post($post, true);
    $idarticoloFr = wp_insert_post($post, true);

    $polylang->model->set_post_language($idarticolo, 'it');
    $polylang->model->set_post_language($idarticoloEn, 'en');
    $polylang->model->set_post_language($idarticoloEs, 'es');
    $polylang->model->set_post_language($idarticoloFr, 'fr');

    $polylang->model->save_translations('post', $idarticolo, array('en' => $idarticoloEn));
    $polylang->model->save_translations('post', $idarticolo, array('es' => $idarticoloEs));
    $polylang->model->save_translations('post', $idarticolo, array('fr' => $idarticoloFr));
```

I insert the post in italian, and then I create the corresponding translations in the the other languages.

Thank you again for your help!

M :)

Answer (score 4):

Update [@Mauro's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224278/polylang-translation-of-a-custom-post-created-by-wp-insert-post/224358#224358) based Polylang version 2.5.3.

```
....
    if ($idarticolo = wp_insert_post($post, true)) {
        $posts = array(
            'en' => '',
            'es' => '',
            'fr' => '',
        );

        // inserisco l'articolo nelle altre lingue: En Es Fr
        foreach ($posts as $language => $value) {
            $posts[$language] = wp_insert_post($post, true);
        }

        if (function_exists('pll_set_post_language') 
            && function_exists('pll_save_post_translations')) {

            pll_set_post_language($idarticolo, 'it');
            foreach ($posts as $language => $value) {
                pll_set_post_language($value, $language);
            }

            pll_save_post_translations(array_merge(array($idarticolo), $posts));
        }
....
```

To set term language, use `pll_set_term_language`.

To save term translations, use `pll_save_term_translations`.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but with Polylang you can now use: `pll_set_post_language` for this.
So for example:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_args);
pll_set_post_language($post_id, 'en');
```